# Send Mail to Houshold's both Contact

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack

I want to send mail of My Household. My One Household is having 2 Contacts. I want to send Email to both Contact when my opportunity stage is Changed. There is Relation between Contact and opportunity.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a trigger for `after update` on Opportunity, and then compare if `StageName` field has changed by comparing it between `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old`. If it is changed, query for your related Contacts and send them the emails.

Documentation for how to send email from Apex code is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm)